# Is it safe to use nSleep pin of DRV883x Motor driver, as a PWM control?

Tags: motordriver

[DRV883x](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8837.pdf) H-Bridge drivers implement 3 pins to control driver's behavior; IN1/IN2 for DRV8837 and EN/PH for DRV8838. except for these 3 pins, they are pin to pin compatible:

[image: DRV883x control pins]

For a simple, dual H-Bridge motor driver module, I wanted to be able to use both chips in my design according to availability. sure I would change the code for specific pin controls.

For the DRV8837, I need [4 PWM output from MCU](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109534/193792) for dual H-bridges; each one connected to one of INx pins of DRV8837s. despite being a little demanding, it is fine (I can use some logic gates to reduce PWM pin counts).

But for the DRV8838, it seems the PWM control is not possible at all; the PH pin reverses the bridge and PWM on EN pin, brakes.

### The Question:

Can I use the nSleep pin for a reasonable low frequency PWM control?

If possible, the design would be intact for both chips as the nSleep pin have the same behavior (coast) for both chips. also there would be just one PWM pin per driver and the other control pins would be just simple GPIO.

Comment: 30uS wake up time could be problematic. No problem for low frequency PWM.

Comment: You may see some issues from the back-EMF when you Hi-Z the outputs. Use some bi-directional TVS diodes on the motor outputs to suppress transients. This is good practice anyway.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser considering a worst case wake up time of 50us, to achieve the maximum duty cycle, the period should be about 500us so a 100% duty cycle would be 450/500 = 90%. which seems fine. so the frequency of 2KHz is somehow possible. 1KHz or lower would be quite good then.